# Differential Geometry Textbook for PDE students

Tags: differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations, book-recommendation

I am a graduate student in partial differential equations. When I was reading the literature sometimes I came across concepts from geometry, such as curvature, Riemannian geometry, and so on.

I took differential geometry as an undergraduate but forgot a lot of it, and the textbooks at that time were biased towards differential geometry students, in other words I thought it was too specialized. So I want to review with another book.

So I would like to ask what is a relatively simple differential geometry textbook. My personal guess; It would suit me better if it was written by an expert in partial differential equations.

*Note: My major is toward free boundary problems and fluid mechanics, not geometric analysis.*

Comment: Riemannian Geometry by do Carmo. I don't know of a more comprehensive and intuitive introduction. There are other books like Petersen's which cover a lot more content and may be more appealing to you, as they are more analytic. However, such books are thought for a 1 year graduate course. do Carmo can be easily covered in one semester.

Comment: Check out Jost’s text. He should have more of a PDE slant.

Comment: You might be interested in “Toward a geometry of differential equations” by Bryant, Griffiths, and Hsu.

Comment: Jost’s book emphasizes the role of PDEs in differential geometry more than other books.